# randomly stacking pancakes

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

A very interesting probability problem. I don't know if it has a name, but I'm rephrasing it in terms of stacking pancakes.

Suppose there are $N$ stacks, and one places pancakes on them randomly (in that each pancake is placed on a random stack uniformly).

We say the $j$-th pancake of a stack is "buried" if all other stacks have at least $j$ pancakes as well. (e.g., the 1st pancake is buried when all stacks have one pancake.)

Now the question is, how many more pancakes does it take to bury the $k$-th pancake?

Comment: Number of pancakes total is ?

Comment: @herbsteinberg unlimited

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to the "coupon collector's problem" or "dixie cup problem".
The expected number of pancakes required to bury the $j$-th pancake is known to be asymptotic to $N \log N + N (j-1) \log \log N$.  You're asking about the  number of additional pancakes, after burying the $j$-th, required to bury the $k$-th.  By linearity of expectation, the expected additional number is
$$
N(k-j)\log \log N
$$
to leading order.